# Keep receiving "too many initializers" error

Tags: c, visual-studio

I am currently try to code for an assignment and just when I thought I could be done I keep getting the too many initializers error and it's an assignment so it must be an int

This is my structure:

```
struct Address {
    int streetNumber;
    char streetName[41];
    int apartmentNumber;
    char postalCode[8];
    char city[41];
};
```

This is my code:

```
int main(void) {
    struct Address addy = { { 0,"",0,"","" } };
```

When I drop the second `{}` it works, but the server I'm uploading on will not accept it unless I'm using double `{}`.

Answer (score 3):

The initializer below is a problem

```
struct Address addy = { { 0,"",0,"","" } };
```

since the first member of the `struct Address`, namely `streetNumber`, cannot be initialized with `{ 0,"",0,"","" }`.

That's what the compiler is warning you about.

You have an extra pair of braces. Change that line to:

```
struct Address addy = { 0, "", 0, "", "" };
```

Make similar changes to the other lines where you see that error.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the double braces where you're using double braces.  A correct initializer for the structure type:

```
struct Address
{
    int streetNumber;
    char streetName[41];
    int apartmentNumber;
    char postalCode[8];
    char city[41];
};
```

would be:

```
struct Address addr1 =
{
    319,                    // Street number
    "Honeydew Road",        // Street name
    207,                    // Apartment number
    "RG13 2PQ",             // Postal code
    "Reading"               // City
};
```

Using C99 and designated initializers, you could use:

```
struct Address addr2 =
{
    .apartmentNumber = 0,
    .streetNumber = 719,
    .streetName = "Persimmon Way",
    .city = "London",
    .postalCode = "EC1A 3JN",
};
```

Note that with designated initializers, the order isn't critical.

If you're insistent on using double braces, then note that you can enclose the initializer for a regular scalar variables in braces (or not):

```
int i1 = 0;       // Legitimate
int i2 = { 0 };   // Also legitimate
```

However, within a structure initializer, you cannot use braces around scalars, but you can around arrays:

```
struct Address addy = { 0, { "" }, 0, { "" }, { "" } };
```

Trying to enclose either `0` in braces leads to compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Address addy = { { 0,"",0,"","" } }
```

You try to initialize a structure with a compound literal that is not compatible with the structure `Address`.

It tries to match the compound literal `{ { 0,"",0,"","" } }` with your structure and because the unification fails, you get that error.

If you cut the outside parenthesis (which could successfully unify an incomplete (or complete with size=1) array of structures Address) or if your structure Address would be nested in other structure, the unification could succeed.

So you need to write

```
 struct Address addy = { 0,"",0,"","" }
```

Answer (score 0):

you used curly once more.

code that you make means addy.streetNumber = { 0," ",0," "," " };

and it makes error. becuase streetNumber's type is just "int", it can't have various values.

the right code is

struct Address Addy = { 0, " ", 0, " ", 0 };

have a nice day dude.

Answer (score -1):

You made a curious statement in your post:

> When I drop the second `{}` it works, but the server I'm uploading on will not accept it unless I'm using double `{}`.

The double `{}` syntax will work if you declare `addy` as an array:

```
struct Address addy[] = { { 0,"",0,"","" } };
```

Or, if `Address` was declared with its members embedded within another struct:

```
struct Address {
    struct {
        int streetNumber;
        char streetName[41];
        int apartmentNumber;
        char postalCode[8];
        char city[41];
    };
};
```

Comment: or as an embedded structure